# MVVM ViewModel and Model Responsibilities (WPF)

Tags: mvvm, model, viewmodel

I am trying to understand the MVVM pattern and I don't clearly get the responsibilities of VM and M. I am trying to work on an wpf example with a Person class (with firstName, lastName and dateOfBirth). I have created such a class in my Model folder. Now I want a collection (an ObservableCollection) of the Person class that I want to bind to my View. Where should I maintain this collection? In ViewModel or Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF) They created very similar program to yours.
In **MODEL** you should have class Person and add persons to collection.
In **VIEWMODEL** ICmmand etc. Read data from Model and push to View.
In **View** just display data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Was looking for a good example like that.